# Defining Firebase default in angular 2

Tags: firebase, angular

I'm new to angular 2, so be patient!

I'm trying to put together `Angular2` and `Firebase` to have a real time app to update information on the page. By looking at the `Firebase` [github for Angular2](https://github.com/angular/angularFire2), they say to inject `Firebase` and also define a base `url` for the whole app, like so:

```
import {FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase} from 'angularfire2';

bootstrap(App, [
  FIREBASE_PROVIDERS,
  defaultFirebase('https://my.firebaseio.com')
]);
```

The problem is, I'm using AngularRouter defined on the `bootstrap` as well. When I try to initiate the app like this:

```
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router'
import {FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase} from 'angularfire2'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    FIREBASE_PROVIDERS,
    defaultFirebase('https://my.firebaseio.com') //In my code I'm using my own url
]);
```

I get this error:

> angular2-polyfills.js:1243 SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(…)

My structure is like this:

```
app.component.ts
boot.ts
--home/home.component.ts
--user/user.component.ts
--post/post.component.ts
```

And the `firebase` is going to be used on the user and post `component` (at least for this test).

I know, based on the [Angular doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html) we should avoid this type of declaration on a root level because it will create an instance of each independent. But in this case, isn't it necessary to declare it here?

What is going on and how can I solve this?

---

#### Edited:

As requested, this is my `html` file:

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular 2 Firebase</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js"></script>

    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {        
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
           }
        });
        System.import('app/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
```

**Note:** The error only appear when I insert the code for default `firebase` in the `boot.ts`. Before I do this, the application works just fine!

Comment: Could you provide the content of your HTMP entry file? Thanks!

Comment: @ThierryTemplier what do you mean by htmp file? Did you meant html? I'll updatethequestion

Comment: Yes sorry ;-) I can't see the angularfire2 library into your HTML file... I think that it's the person of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include **angularfire2** into your HTML file in your SystemJS configuration:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    firebase: '/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-web.js',
    angularfire2: ' node_modules/angularfire2'
  },
  packages: {      
    angularfire2: {
      main: 'angularfire2.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  },
});
```

to be able to inject elements from this library.

You also need to remove the `script` element for Firebase in the `head` of your HTML page:

```
<!-- script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js"></script -->
```

The library needs to be installed using `npm install firebase` and referenced from the SytemJS configuration.

See the following HTML page as a reference:

- https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/test/e2e/firebase_list/index.html

Comment: Yes, I had saw this somewhere before and did tried, but the same error is happening.. If I manually add the script via script tag, the difference is that manually, I even get another error: `require is not defined` and with your method, nothing changes.

Comment: You could try to use a `main` element into the package entry for `angularfire2` or `import ... from 'angularfire2/angularfire2'`. The reason of the "require is not defined" error is that you need to configure the library into SystemJS...

Comment: Could you show me an example to configure the System for required? I'm starting with Angular2 so this is kind of new to me. I change the path to `angularfire2/angularfire2` and now, with both methods, I get the `required` error

Comment: I don't know why, but there is always a new error. This time it says defaultFirebase is not a function. I don't know what may be happening.. I've put my files (without the node_modules folder) on my github account, if it's not ask too much, could take a look? https://github.com/celsomtrindade/Firebase

Comment: Well, it finally worked. But I was watching a conference about this and they said to use one of them, the result would be the same. Do you have any idea why?